# MySQL selecting latest occurrences of a GROUP BY'd field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has a non-unique id, `id`, a status, `status` (which I'm trying to get), and a timestamp of when it was inserted, `inserted`.  I need to select the most recent occurrence of each `id` ordered by the `id`.  I have the following table ordered by `inserted`:

```
id  |  status  |  inserted
------------------------------------
4   | approved | 2016-08-09 15:51:52
5   | denied   | 2016-08-09 15:52:36
5   | pending  | 2016-08-09 15:55:05
```

The results I need are:

```
id  |  status  |  inserted
------------------------------------
4   | approved | 2016-08-09 15:51:52
5   | pending  | 2016-08-09 15:55:05
```

I have the following SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM table
   GROUP BY id
   ORDER BY inserted
```

and I'm getting these results:

```
id  |  status  |  inserted
------------------------------------
4   | approved | 2016-08-09 15:51:52
5   | denied   | 2016-08-09 15:52:36
```

The solution is probably an easy one, but I've racked my brain on this long enough trying things such as inner selects and whatnot.  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I had to use the third option from the linked duplicate question to get the results I expected (the one with the `LEFT JOIN`). I assume it was because I was using a `DATETIME` type, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*
from
    <T> t inner join
    (select id, max(inserted) as max_inserted from <T> group by id) as m
        on m.id = t.id and m.max_inserted = t.inserted
```

or

```
 select
     id,
     (
         select status from <T> t2
         where t2.id = t.id and t2.inserted = max_inserted
     ) as status,
     max(inserted) as max_inserted
 from <T>
 group by id
```

You can try searching for "mysql latest per group" or something like that for alternatives more specific to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent record for each `id`, then don't use `group by`.  Instead:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.inserted = (select max(t2.inserted) from table t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```